# Continuous Partials and Analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

In the sixth edition of James Ward Brown’s *Complex Variables and Applications*, page 57, a proof of the reflection principle is provided. I’m confused about a step pertaining the continuity of partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of the function given the fact that it is analytic in a domain:

> Now, because $f(x+it)$ is an analytic function of $x+it$, the first-order partial derivatives of the functions $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ are continuous throughout $D$...

For context, $D$ is a domain symmetric about a portion of the real axis in the complex plane. $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ are the real and imaginary components of $f$, respectively. I know that differentiability implies continuity of the functions $u$ and $v$ themselves, but why does it also imply that of their first-order partials?

Of course, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is analytic, then so is $f'$. But $f'(x+yi)=u_x(x,y)+v_x(x,y)i=v_y(x,y)-u_y(x,y)i$, by the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So, $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$, and $v_y$ are continuous.

Comment: Sir, from above, how you concluded that, $u_x, u_y, v_x$ & $v_y$  are continuous?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics That's because $u$ and $v$ are analytic.

Comment: Sir, sorry but I couldn't get it. Analyticity implies continuity of partial derivatives? Further, $u$ & $v$ are real ans imaginary parts of $f$, so how they were analytic?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics They are [real analytic functions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Real_analytic_function).

Comment: Sir, can we say that, as $f' = u_x + iv_x= v_y-iu_y$ is analytic and so it is continuous. Thus its real & imaginary parts that is, $u_x, v_x, u_y, v_y$ are continuous.

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was going through proof of Cauchy's integral theorem, using Greens theorem. I don't understand why it needs an additional assumption that $f'(z)$ is continuous in region $R$. (It is already given that, $f(z)=u+iv$ is analytic in $R$ and hence $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x =v_y-iu_y $ is also analytic and so is continuous! Therefore, it's real & imaginary parts that is, the partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ are continuous. Which is the requirement to for applying Green's theorem!)

Comment: @GeneralMathematics That hypothesis is **not** needed, but the theorem becomes much easier to prove if we assume it.